# Set password on published zip artifact in azure pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have this azure pipeline which creates a zip file of the build output.
is there any way to set password on that created zip file automatically from the pipeline ?
With a password taken from the user when running the pipeline, I mean the user get popup to type the password he needs to protect the artifact with.

```
variables:
solution: '**/*.sln'
buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package     /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true     /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip"     /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  inputs:
    # SourceFolder: '$(agent.builddirectory)'
    Contents: |
        **\ABBExpressionPlugin.dll
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)' 
    includeRootFolder: true 
    archiveType: 'zip' 
    tarCompression: 'gz' 
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip' 
    replaceExistingArchive: true 


    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'ibaPlugInDLL'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Answer (score 1):

> is there any way to set password on that created zip file automatically
> from the pipeline ?

You can use the extension [Secure Zip](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Delta-N.ArchiveWithEncryption) with `Secure Zip` task to create a zip archive that is protected by a password in pipeline. And use another `Secure Unzip` task to extract a password protected zip file.

However, it will not popup a window asking you to enter your password, because the pipeline is not interactive if your are running as a service. You can [set a secret variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables) in pipeline and set a password as the value. Then you can use the variable in the tasks to encrypt and decrypt the zip files.

```
- task: ArchiveFilesWithEncryption@2
  inputs:
    Source: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    Dest: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    Encryption: '$(secure)'
- task: ExtractFilesWithEncryption@1
  inputs:
    Source: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    Dest: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId)'
    Encryption: '$(secure)'
```

Comment: i was looking for a solution without 3rd part extenssion !

Comment: @B.j There isn't a specific built-in task in Azure DevOps to achieve that. However you can try to add command line or poswershell task to run your custom scripts to encrypt and decrypt the zip files (Reference [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17641/create-encrypted-password-protected-zip-file)). But please note that, you need an agent runs as interactive mode, otherwise you can not see the popup windows to enter password, and you need to remote to the agent server to enter the password.